# Local / Session storage in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There are a number of modules available to deal with Local/Session storage from within AngularJs apps. Two of the more popular ones are:

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

My question - is a separate AngularJS module to handle local or session storage really necessary? They are both very simple APIs. I feel like I am missing something. What do I gain by including an extra module into my code, over just using the regular HTML5 methods? Is there an accepted best practice for handling storage in AngularJS?

Comment: It never even occurred to me to search for one. As you say, browser storage is exceedingly straightforward. I just used straight JavaScript. I looked at those two projects which you mentioned and cannot see that they add anything. It is possible that we are both overlooking something, but I say just use plain JS.